# Capturing the Facebook Like onclick event

Tags: facebook

Normally in HTML you can put div boxes on top of one another and if you click in the bottom box (the last one in the HTML) the onclick event will bubble up through the DOM to the other boxes, so that each box could do something with the onclick event if it wanted.  But if you put a Facebook Like button in a div, clicking Like button does not pass the onclick event to the enclosing div.

Does anyone know a way to make this happen, so that the Like click can not only do the Facebook thing but also trigger an action on my page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should [subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) for `edge.create` and/or `edge.remove` events:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
  function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The like button is located in an iframe and you won't get events bubbling up from the iframe into your dom events.

Comment: While that's true, Facebook JS-SDK provide custom events for triggering like button...

Answer (score 0):

My Idea about the Problem is to get the picture and to handle the click event on this picture. So you can capture it on your page and forward to facebook.